# What is use of Applications table in OpenIddict

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openiddict

Please explain me what is use of Applications table in OpenIddict. 
I am following this awesome tutorial http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/
It works perfectly. I have misunderstanding of functions of Applications table which was added for OpenIddict.

Currently, my Front end (Angularjs) + Back end (Web.API with ASP.NET Core and OpenIddict) work fine on one server. The Front end receives tokens and uses it in requests. The Back end generates tokens and evaluate them. All good, but Applications table does not have any records.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Applications` table contains the [OAuth2 client applications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2) that are allowed to use your identity server.

---

Adding a new entry is mandatory when using interactive flows like [authorization code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) or [implicit](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.1), as client applications have to send a valid `client_id`: OpenIddict will reject the authorization request if the `client_id` is missing or doesn't correspond to an application you fully trust (i.e an application stored in the `Applications` table).

The same rule applies to the [client credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4), that also requires a valid `client_id`.

---

In contrast, there's one case where sending a `client_id` is not mandatory: when using the [resource owner password credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3), as demonstrated in the blog post you mentioned.

The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2.1) explicitly states that a client application making a token request MAY send its `client_id`, which means that this parameter is not mandatory.

> A client MAY use the "client_id" request parameter to identify itself when sending requests to the token endpoint.

When no `client_id` can be extracted from the token request, OpenIddict has no way to determine the identity of the application. In this case, the `client_id`-related checks are skipped and the request is processed without using the `Applications` table. That's why your application works without having to populate the `Applications` table.

---

Though useful for logging purposes, sending a `client_id` doesn't make `grant_type=password` requests safer, as everybody can impersonate an application by re-using the same `client_id`, unless the application was declared as confidential and was assigned client credentials (read "server-side apps only"). In this case, a malicious caller cannot send a valid token request without knowing the `client_secret`.

---

In OpenIddict, there's also one case where adding an explicit app registration is useful: when using the [introspection middleware](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection) to validate access tokens (instead of the JWT bearer middleware).

As [required by the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.1), callers must authenticate to use the introspection endpoint: if OpenIddict can't find a corresponding entry in the `Applications` table, the request will be rejected and the introspection middleware will never work.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer.